# Как создать одну таблицу из двух Python?

Tags: python

Помогите, пожалуйста, разобраться как решить задачу Python 3!

Есть 2 таблицы, в которых идет подсчет сообщений, которые пишут пользователи в двух разных чатах. Реализовано как 2 dataframe.

```
d1= pd.DataFrame({'name': ['Маша', 'Юра', 'Витя'], 'Кол-во': [4, 2, 7]})
d2= pd.DataFrame({'name': ['Витя', 'Маша', 'Юра'], 'Кол-во': [8, 1, 4]})
```

Первый dataframe – первый чат:

| Имя пользователя | Количество сообщений в чате |
| --- | --- |
| Маша | 4 |
| Юра | 2 |
| Витя | 7 |

Второй dataframe – второй чат:

| Имя пользователя | Количество сообщений в чате |
| --- | --- |
| Витя | 8 |
| Маша | 1 |
| Юра | 4 |

Нужно 2 dataframe объединить в один, который будет содержать сведения о пользователе и их количествах сообщений в 2х разных чатах.
Результат имеет такой вид:

| Имя пользователя | Количество сообщений в чате 1 | Количество сообщений в чате 2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Витя | 7 | 8 |
| Маша | 4 | 1 |
| Юра | 2 | 4 |

Помогите, пожалуйста, разобраться какими методами действовать?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Основной метод - `merge()` - объединяет фреймы по указанному ключевому столбцу. Плюс косметика для приведения в целевой вид.

```
d1 = pd.DataFrame({'Имя пользователя': ['Маша', 'Юра', 'Витя'], 'Количество сообщений в чате': [4, 2, 7]})
d2 = pd.DataFrame({'Имя пользователя': ['Витя', 'Маша', 'Юра'], 'Количество сообщений в чате': [8, 1, 4]})
out = d1.merge(d2, on='Имя пользователя', suffixes=(' 1', ' 2')).sort_values('Количество сообщений в чате 1', ascending=False)
print(out)
```

```
  Имя пользователя  Количество сообщений в чате 1  Количество сообщений в чате 2
2             Витя                              7                              8
0             Маша                              4                              1
1              Юра                              2                              4
```